# Eventarc to trigger Cloud Run by Firestore document creation event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I am trying to set up a basic Eventarc trigger for triggering Cloud Run when a new Firestore document is added.

I set it up as depicted in the screenshot below (region: global; resource: any). Then I create a new document in Firestore (database location: `europe-west3`). The Cloud Run service in `europe-north1` does not get triggered; moreover, no information about the event shows up in the trigger monitoring (see the screenshot).

What am I doing wrong?

Firestore log:
[image]

Trigger details:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a day, but here is the thing. To use Eventarc for Firestore events, you need to enable Compute Engine API audit logging, **NOT** the Firestore/Datastore API. You can do that in [IAM and admin -> Audit logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit?_ga=2.159584445.1279465485.1678126147-820457578.1669297987).

It does not seem self-evident to me. It would be nice if the documentation had that explicitly about the Firestore vs. Compute Engine APIs.

Here is the configuration that works:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What else did you have to do, I'm still not able to get my cloud run instance to be called when I add a document to firestore. I've tried with Compute engine as well as Firestore audit logs. Anything else you would recommend to check?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events), there is a more adapted event to trigger a `Cloud Run` service after adding a document in the `Firestore` database, example :

```bash
gcloud eventarc triggers create your-trigger \
  --location ${REGION} --service-account your-sa-email \
  --destination-run-service your-service  \
  --event-filters type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written \
  --event-filters methodName=google.firestore.v1.Firestore.CreateDocument \
  --event-filters serviceName=firestore.googleapis.com
```

In this example I used an event filter with `methodName=google.firestore.v1.Firestore.CreateDocument`

Comment: I tried it, too. Still does not work. I redeployed the Cloud Run service to the europe-west3 to endure geographical consistency. I see the writes in Firestore log but no trigger events.

What could be on the way of the Firestore event to the Eventarc trigger?